# Nightmare debugging UNIX program in windows

Tags: debugging, unix, gdb, elf

I've a stripped binary file in UNIX ELF32-i386 format , I don't have its source, I need to debug it and perform dynamic analysis on it,its a study project. I've successfully disassembled it using IDA PRO free and was able to run it on Portable Ubuntu program. but I cannot find a way to debug it step by step on Windows 7 (32-bit) and Intel processor. I've tried MinGw gdb but its not running the program gives error 193. If anybody could please suggest a free solution to this problem, that would be of help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can run it on your portable Ubuntu system, then you can debug it, too. If `gdb` isn't installed, run `sudo apt-get install gdb` to install it. You can also install VirtualBox on Windows and then download an Ubuntu distribution to run in the VM. Windows 7 cannot directly run Unix binaries.

Comment: Sir I've installed MinGW GDB, but its not running that binary gives error 193, I'll try that by gdb in protable ubuntu as well. Thanks for your kind reply.

Comment: Sir, Could you please help me with this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47943472/unix-sdin-redirect-menu-driven-program